# Updating vc6 code to vs2005 - missing two DLLs

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have compiled and built  my VC6 application code in vs2005, but while running I am getting an error saying could not load the DLL.  Once I check this with dependency walker I found that ieshims.dll and wer.dll are missing. I searched for those dll's but I could not fine them.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a manifest dependency error. If the computer you're trying to run your application on does not have Visual Studio installed, you must have the [redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=200b2fd9-ae1a-4a14-984d-389c36f85647) runtime installed for the CRT.

Next time, paste the full error.

Answer (score 0):

ieshims.dll is actually a dependency of Dependency Walker itself.  The file resides in %ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer.

The solution to your problem is to add %ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer to your PATH environment variable.  This was done as part of the install prior to Windows 7.